# prevent image from submission if field is empty

Tags: php, mysql

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in ......... on line 44,

I'm getting this error when I submitted image field empty. If I submit with an image the form works fine with no errors, and inserts data into each database (4 tables) sucessfully.

I'm building a form with a lot of fields and different tables in a single form.

PHP connection code:

```
//database connection
ini_set('display_errors','on');
try {
    $host       = 'localhost';
    $dbname     = 'parent';
    $user       = 'root';
    $password   = '';

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$user,$password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $e->getMessage();
    //die("Something went wrong please contact your adminstrator");
}
```

HTML/PHP upload code:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   Input field-1
   Input field-2
   Input field-3
   ......
   ....
   .....
   Input field-10

   $insert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO parent (field-1,field-2,.......,field-10) VALUES (:field-1,......,field-10)");
```

Now this is the code for inserting into the gallery where I'm getting the error when the gallery (image) field is submitted empty.

Here I'm checking if the image field is empty, if it's empty it should do nothing - don't insert blank data in gallery table. I have used a separate table for the gallery

```
if (!empty($_FILES['multipleFile']['name'])) {//line 44 where im getting error when submitted without image
            
      $multiplefile = $_FILES['multipleFile']['name'];

      foreach ($multiplefile as $name => $value) {
        
        $allowImg = array('png','jpeg','jpg',''); 

        $fileExnt = explode('.', $multiplefile[$name]);

        if (in_array($fileExnt[1], $allowImg)) {

            if ($_FILES['multipleFile']['size'][$name] > 0 && $_FILES['multipleFile']['error'][$name]== 0) {
              
              $fileTmp = $_FILES['multipleFile']['tmp_name'][$name];
                  
              $newFile =  rand(). '.'. $fileExnt[1];

              $target_dir = 'upload/'.$newFile; 

              if (move_uploaded_file($fileTmp, $target_dir)) {
                //3rd database table to store multiple image
                  $gallery = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO gallery (gpranet_id,image,caption) VALUES (:parent_id,:image,:caption)");
                  $gallery->execute([
                        ':parent_id'=>$lastenterid,
                        ':image'=>$newFile,
                        ':caption'=>$newFile,
                    ]);
              }
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

HTML form segment:

```
//Uploading multiple image
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="file" name="multipleFile[]" multiple>
</div>  

<div class="form-group">
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="publish" value="Submit">
</div>

</form>
```

How can i debug this error?

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in ......... on line 44

which I'm getting when submitting an empty image field. If the user doesn't need to insert an image I want it to empty and don't want to send an empty value to the database.

Comment: Please learn the difference between a "database" and a "table" - I have corrected your terminology throughout.

Comment: I think you should check `if (!empty($_FILES['multipleFile'])` rather than checking the name property specifically. Or possibly `count()` it instead.

Comment: P.S. The error message doesn't match the line where you're saying the error is, though...you're not trying to access an offset of `1` in that line of code.

Comment: my mistake i worte database instead of table....
but my server is showing error on line 42 ( if (in_array($fileExnt[1], $allowImg)) { )
is there any syntax and way to get more details about this error...

Comment: if (in_array($fileExnt[1], $allowImg)), i think $fileExnt[1], so its excepting 1 but when i submit, its returning `Array ( [0] => `, is this the reason bcz array desnt have any value but its excepting at least 1 value

Comment: **(solved)** array is expecting at least one value but when i submit empty field is not passing any value thats why error is generated